# How was dataflow analysis performed before SSA?

Tags: programming, compilers

If we look at something like [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) or the [GNU Compiler Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), [Dalvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) and many others, their [intermediate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation) (IR) uses [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) (Static Single Assignment form), as part of their [Data-Flow Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis), to essentially make sure that variables are immutable, so that they are easier to analyse and this makes it easier to implement optimisations that alter the way a computation is made, for example:

- [Common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination): it is easier to identify a common subexpression in an SSA language, since it's essentially a node in a binary tree, which can be compared, along with the daughter nodes.
- [Constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding)/constant propagation: of course, if two variables are immutable, then it's much easier to prove that they're going to have exactly the same value.
- [Dead store elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_store): For each value calculated by a program, SSA shows exactly where it is used, so of course as a side effect it will also *prove* that it is not used (that is, it may be discarded).

And a similar bullet point could be made for many other kinds of optimisations that compilers perform, especially the ones that typically happen *before the first passes of machine code generation*.

The problem is that SSA was apparently only introduced in 1988, but I am sure that optimisations that *alter the dataflow* such as the above, were attempted long before then. They certainly have been mentioned before then, going by the citations on the Wikipedia page for global subexpression elimination for example. So what were common ways to approach this problem before 1988 when SSA was first mentioned?

---

**Clarification**: I'm not asking if there were compilers that didn't bother! There's a use-case for them as well, but what I'm interested in is some of the methods that compilers used to perform the dataflow analysis and how they allowed for the optimisation to take place.

Comment: I think the answer is "with difficulty". In the past, compilers were worse at optimising code. SSA is one to the technologies that improved them.

Comment: The advantage of SSA is that is it one technique that can be used to solve several different problems, e.g. constant propagation, dead code elimination, strength reduction, register allocation, etc. There effective practical methods to address each of these separate optimization problems before SSA, and any good book on compiler writing that predates SSA will describe some of them.

Comment: @Raffzahn, thanks for the edit, that's a marked improvement

Comment: I'm just to lazy to think when reading :)) BTW, Dead store elimination goes hand in hand with dead code elimination - as well supported by SSA.

Comment: Just a general remark: While compiler design was already early on a topic for research (think Pascal), real world compilers where hacks of many different and rather empiric designs. It wasn't until the 90s that 'scientific' (and open) designs offered results on par with proprietary constructions.

Comment: One "classic" reference source from 10 years before SSA was Aho and Ullman, "Principles of Compiler Design". https://www.amazon.co.uk/Principles-Compiler-Design-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201100738. If you want to study the history of compiler writing, compare that with Aho, Sethi, and Ullman, "Compilers - Principles, Techniques and Tools" from 10 years later. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201100886/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=QWHQQX81HFMSBT9JVYP4

Comment: GCC did all its optimizations on its RTL representation, which it still uses today for later optimization passes, including CSE and DSE passes, after the GIMPLE (SSA) passes (which also has CSE/DSE passes).. An exception was (and probably still is) simple constant folding, which is was done at the parse tree level, since it had to be to implement things like `int foo[3 + 4];`.

Comment: @RossRidge: For straight-line code, one could do a reasonably-decent job of optimizing by starting with a parse-tree representation by keeping a cache of expression values and the associated parse trees, and invalidating any cache entry whenever anything happens suggest that its value might be disturbed (e.g. code uses `&` on an object whose value is used in an expression, accesses a `volatile`, etc).  This wouldn't yield perfect code, but it would be a lot better than `gcc -O0` without the compatibility problems associated with higher optimization levels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original FORTRAN I compiler, which was later expanded into the FORTRAN II compiler,
did some pretty sophisticated optimizations. It was written in 1954–1956, back when many
programmers thought it was impossible for a computer to generate machine code comparable
in efficiency to what humans could write. Hence the FORTRAN team focused heavily on
getting the compiler to produce an efficient object program.

One of the authors, Peter Sheridan, wrote an article in 1959 about the method used by the
compiler to translate expressions (citation below). Here is what it says regarding common
subexpression elimination:

> The next stage of optimization involves the “elimination” of common subexpressions, so as
> to avoid redundant computation. This is accomplished in two steps:
>
> 1. Beginning with *S<sub>L</sub>*, the last segment in Π̅(Φ), and for each *i* ≤ *L*, the
>    set of all *S<sub>j</sub>* with *j* < *i* is examined for the occurrence of an
>    *S<sub>j</sub>* = *S<sub>i</sub>*. As soon as some *S*<sub>j</sub> = *S<sub>j</sub>*,
>    *S<sub>j</sub>* is eliminated from Π̅(Φ), and all references to *S<sub>j</sub>* replaced
>    by references to *S<sub>i</sub>*, i.e., if some Ψ<sub>*k*</sub> = *j*, then *j* is set
>    equal to *i*.
> 2. Having eliminated, by (1), common segments, we now eliminate common subexpressions.
>    Beginning with *S<sub>L</sub>*, and for each *i* ≤ *L*, the set of all *S<sub>j</sub>*
>    with *j* < *i* is examined for the occurrence of more than one reference to
>    *S<sub>i</sub>*, i.e., the occurrence of Ψ<sub>*m*</sub>, Ψ<sub>*n*</sub>, with *m* ≠ *n*
>    and Ψ<sub>*m*</sub> = Ψ<sub>*n*</sub> = *i*. If and only if this is the case is
>    *S<sub>i</sub>* tagged as a common subexpression (what we call a cs-type segment).
>
> Procedures (1) and (2) together assure the elimination of outermost common subexpressions.
> Thus, if
>
> > Φ = A * (B * C) + SINF(A * (B * C)),
>
> then
>
> > [Π̅(Φ) = (0,+,1)(0,+,14)(1,*,A)(1,*,7)(7,*,B)(7,*,C)(14,⊕,SINF)(14,⊕,16)(16,*,A) (16,*,22)(22,*,B)(22,*,C)].
>
> Procedures (1) and (2) reduce Π̅ to
>
> > (0,+,16)(0,+,14)(14,⊕,SINF)(14,⊕,16)(16,*,A)(16,*,22)(22,*,B)(22,*,C),
>
> with *S*<sub>16</sub> tagged as a cs-type segment, since Ψ<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> = Ψ<sub>14</sub><sup>2</sup> = 16.

Remember that this was before our modern ideas of how to implement programming languages.
The formalization described in Sheridan's article is rather complicated, and I'm not going
to try to explain the notation in this answer. The point is that early optimization
techniques, from before we came up with things like SSA, were not necessarily ad hoc or
bad or hacky. Quite a bit of thought and mathematical analysis went into the development
of FORTRAN I.

Citation for the article:

P.B. Sheridan. The arithmetic translator-compiler of the IBM FORTRAN automatic coding
system. *Communications of the ACM*, Volume 2, Number 2, February 1959, pages 9–21.
[(PDF)](https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Fortran/102663107.05.01.acc.pdf)

See the Software Preservation Group's website for primary resources on implementations of
other early languages. In many cases source code listings for compilers or interpreters
are available.

- ALGOL: http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL
- Lisp: http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP

Regarding the first FORTRAN compilers, only FORTRAN II's source code seems to have
survived; however, as I mentioned, FORTRAN II was derived directly from FORTRAN I, and the
main changes were extensions. A listing of FORTRAN II can be found in a couple different
forms [here](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/FORTRAN/index.html#Source_code)
(courtesy, again, of the Software Preservation Group).

Answer (score 18):

First, I would like to introduce myself by saying that I am the Zadeck
of the "Wegman and Zadeck" that invented SSA form. Second, I would
like to say that writing optimizing compilers back then was very hard:
optimizing compilers were only produced for the large mainframes from
IBM, CDC, Univac, or DEC.  They were expensive to develop and were
only available on machines that were used for scientific computing.
There were no optimizing compilers for PCs - PCs were too slow and too
small for for the number crunching needed for scientific computing.

The analysis techniques in these optimizing compilers were based on a
series of papers, primarily by Fran Allen, John Cocke, Ken Kennedy,
Jacob Schwartz and Jeffery Ullman.  There were many other people
involved in the area.  Googling these names, and looking at their
bibliographies will find most of the early work because the area was
very small. Some textbooks from that time are listed at the end of
this posting.

Briefly, the idea behind many of these techniques was to analyze the
program enough to produce a set of propositions that you wished to
prove.  These facts would be represented as positions in a vector.
Simple facts, that were either true or false could be represented as a
single bit packed into a word vector, more complex facts took more
space.  You then needed to construct a function for every point in the
program that modeled how the set of facts changed by execution of that
program location.  Then you propagated the information around the
program until you reached a fixed point.  There are a large number of
papers devoted to how you can set up the vectors to solve particular
problems and perform this propagation efficiently.

Asymptotically, the techniques are very slow.  The general forms of
the techniques took between N log(N) and N**2 vector operations over
the program and the size of the vectors scaled with the size of the
program.  Specialized techniques were developed that used only N
vector operations but were only worked on a restricted class of
programs.  SSA form is almost always always linear in the size of the
program so as programs and machines got bigger, it became a better
fit.  Also, SSA form is produced once during the compilation and kept
up to date as the program is transformed.  Data flow analysis has to
be redone for every optimization pass.  Today's optimizing compilers
may perform up to 100 passes.  It was not unusual in these early
compilers for a program that was only 100 lines long to take minutes
to compile with optimization.

You can still see a use of dataflow analysis in a modern project in
the GCC compilers.  The high-level, machine independent, optimizations
are preformed using SSA form, but the low-level machine dependent
backends perform optimizations driven by dataflow analysis.  GCC
predates SSA form becoming mainstream.  It was never consided cost
effective to update the backends given the large number of legacy
architectures that GCC supports.

The following books provide good descriptions of the area.  The first
one is "the Dragon Book".  It was an undergraduate textbook and was
printed in large quantities.  It is likely available on the used
market.  The other two are deeper treatments of the area are likely
impossible to find unless someone has posted them online.

```
@BOOK { Aho86a,
    Title = "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools ",
    Author = "Aho, A. V. and Sethi, R. and Ullman, J. D.",
    Publisher = AddisonWesley,
    Year = 1986,
}
@BOOK { Hecht77a,
    Title = "Flow Analysis of Computer Programs",
    Author = "Hecht, M. S.",
    Publisher = Elsevier,
    Year = 1977,
}
@BOOK { Muchnick81a,
    Title = "Program Flow Analysis",
    Editor = "Muchnick, S. S. and Jones, N. D.",
    Publisher = "Prentice-Hall",
    Year = 1981,
}
```

Comment: How well suited is SSA to a language where accesses to `a[i]` and `b[j]` might access the same storage even if `a!=b` and `i!=j`? IMHO much strife could be avoided if C were split into recognized distinct dialects, one of which would use an abstraction model that would be a good fit for SSA but a poor fit for some tasks, and one of which would process loads and stores using "older" styles of optimization analysis based on sequencing. Do you share my perception that SSA is excellent for some tasks, but compiler writers exhibit a "when all you have is a hammer, everything is a nail" attitude?

Comment: The short answer is, better than in dfa, but not very good.    In general, this kind of alias analysis in a c like language is intractable.   This is not because of the rep of the analysis, but that the semantics of the language allow too much weird stuff to be done to pointer. 

In more modern strongly typed, garbage collected languages it is not possible to play as loose with pointer and so the analysis is more tractable.    The key here is that you cannot do weird stuff or you mess up the gc.

Comment: Why do you suppose compiler writers aren't willing to recognize the legitimacy of C code that doesn't fit the SSA model, and process such code reasonably efficiently, while also offering a dialect that has no pretext of compatibility with all existing legitimate C code but could offer improved performance for code that is amenable to SSA?  A mode which treated all accesses to objects whose address is taken as `volatile` could offer performance that was vastly better than -O0, but compatibility with many other programs that would otherwise require -O0 setting.

Comment: I think you are confusing several issues.   There are likely over several hundred thousand people who have or do program using gcc.   The languages that gcc supports have well defined semantics.   There is no room for deviation from those semantics is considered a bug, a possibly a bug that could be exploited as a security hole.    None of this has anything to do with ssa form.   It has to do with supporting a product that everyone agrees on the meaning of correctness. 

Ssa form is used in most of todays compilers because it supports a semantic model that is easy to reason about

Comment: Is there any specification anywhere that would authorize the way clang and gcc treat https://godbolt.org/z/Evzhd6W6h ?  By my reading of the Standard, behavior would be defined as having `test(y,0)` set `y[0]` to 2 and return 2 if `x` is one element and `y` immediately follows `x`, and setting `y[0]` to 1 and returning 1 otherwise.  Both clang and gcc, however, simultaneously assume that the expression `p+i` is equivalent to `x[1]`, and that the `y[0]` at the end will yield the value that was earlier assigned using an lvalue of the `y[0]` form.  What do you think causes that?

Comment: Is that really what is happening?    What if the loader refused to allocate x and y next to each other?    It would be legal for the loader to pad every global to minimize the damage from people being off by one.   There is a really strong view that people should not write code like this and in many modern languages you actually cannot write this kind of code.

Comment: If the loader placed `x` and `y` separately, the code would be correct.  If an implementation would refrain from ever placing objects adjacent to each other, and specified that it was only suitable for linking with others that did likewise, the optimization would be sound.  The problem is that there's nothing that would *forbid* `x` and `y` from being placed adjacent, but the code would behave erroneously if that were to occur.  Clang and gcc use an abstraction model where things will almost always work, but will behave contrary to specification if certain things occur which are unlikely...

Comment: ...but are not guaranteed by spec to be impossible.  Splitting the language into a dialect which would explicitly require compilers allow for such possibilities, and a dialect which would explicitly waive such requirement by e.g. treating certain otherwise-valid pointer equality comparisons as UB would reduce the discrepancy between optimizations that are likely to be safe and useful, versus those which are actually sound.

Comment: You are fighting against a strong current.  Languages like C and C++ are in decline largely because they have these holes.   The development of languages like Python and Java, with checked pointers and precise garbage collection, is because the small gain that one gets by playing these games does not come close to offset increased maintenance costs; especially for large complex software.  You can download both GCC and LLVM and define your own language and publish it.  Getting a large following may be more difficult.

Comment: C and C++ may be in decline as a general-purpose application languages, but for many embedded and systems programming tasks, *no good alternatives exist*.  On many platforms, it would be possible to bootstrap an operating system using nothing but C code, without using any syntactic features that didn't exist in K&R2 C beyond some means of configuring address ranges and forcing function code or static-const objects to be placed at certain addresses.  Such a notion would be absurd in Java or Python.  Unfortunately, clang and gcc provide no way of disabling optimizations that are...

Comment: ...appropriate and useful even when performing low-level tasks, and those which create absurd obstacles to writing code that can be guaranteed correct by specification.  I don't think it's possible to write a language spec which classifies as UB every construct that clang and gcc don't seek to process reliably, but still allows the vast majority of systems programming tasks to be accomplished essentially as conveniently as they could be in a compiler that made a good faith effort to behave consistent with -O0 in all cases that would be likely to matter.

Comment: In a good language, there shouldn't be an excessive difference in the difficulty of the following tasks: (1) write a source-code program from which the current version of a compiler will produce a machine-code program whose behavior is guaranteed by the target platform specification in a manner meeting application requirements; (2) write a source-code program which is guaranteed by a combination of specifications to yield a machine-code program meeting requirements.  Unfortunately, some people are pushing to widen the gap for many tasks rather than shrink it.

Answer (score 7):

Quite frequently it wasn't.

When your compiler is running on a 286 with 512K of memory, using floppies for storage, the optimizations by the compiler are very localized if they exist at all. Frequently the compiler wasn't even bright enough to eliminate variables that were declared but never used, let alone ones that got assignments but were never read.

You know that saying 'C is a high-level assembly language'? That was very close to literally true in the early days. At that time the compilers pretty much translated statements from the language into an equivalent assembly form, assigned registers and memory locations on the stack as needed and called it a day. There simply wasn't CPU or storage for the compiler to get particularly intelligent.

Comment: Well, true, and I should not complain with such a nice and true quote about the merits of C :)) But I can't halt to note that the world didn't start with PCs nor their compilers - even thru they restarted from scratch. Also, C is a newcomer to the business. There are many others who got quite interesting optimization strategies already way before the first microprocessor was build - like FORTRAN 66 using statistical analysis to order the three cases of an IF - and they for sure had the CPU and memory to do so.

Comment: True so far as it goes, but Cray Research had been shipping supercomputers for 12 years before 1988. Not to mention other mainframe manufacturers. Actually 512K was a huge amount of memory to run a compiler back then, when the different passes were different overlays. We used to do most of our compile-and link runs (but not executing the program being built) on our IBM S/370s in just 100K bytes.

Comment: Are you claiming that this class of optimisations simply didn't happen back then?

Comment: @Wilson - in quite a few compilers, that's correct. The earlier the compiler was, the less optimizations it performed. Though as alephzero points out, big iron is a different beast, and would have had optimizations much earlier than the PC world.

Comment: The question is about optimising compilers though

Comment: A lot of old programs used the 95-5 rule to leave 95% of the code in the less optimized C/Pascal/Fortran and hand optimize the critical 5% in assembly. The 68k and x86 processors made hand optimization beat out the compilers almost all of the time in the 80s.

Comment: Most of the early compilers used at least *peephole optimization*, a technique that simply looks for repeating patterns of badly generated code (like unnecessary register saves and restores) the compiler builders knew their software frequently generated, and replaced these patterns with faster instructions (or eliminated them completely)

Comment: @MichaelShopsin: The same sort of 95%-5% rule suggests that simple optimizations to harvest low-hanging fruit may be able to eliminate more wasted operations than could be eliminated by any additional optimizations, no matter how brilliant.  For example, a compiler for a machine with six general-purpose registers might keep a "cache" of the 16 most-recently evaluated expressions, invalidating any entry whose value might change, and then during code generation store the result of each expression in whatever register holds the least useful value.  Such an approach wouldn't be perfect, but...

Comment: ...it would be relatively cheap and would eliminate a lot of redundant operations.  If one wanted to go even cheaper, one could simply keep the six most recently evaluated expressions in registers in round-robin fashion.  One could do that even in in a "one-shot" compiler, where it would add almost noting to build time, but still offer a substantial improvement in code efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is the dataflow analysis part of the dragon book. Take common subexpression elimination for example, available expression analysis will be performed to achieve this optimization for non-SSA IR.

Comment: Could you provide some context to this answer? Very few people have the dragon book; at present, this is a link-only answer.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 err, what link?

Comment: @Raffzahn Maybe this one? https://archive.org/details/compilersprincip0000ahoa

Seriously, a reference to a book is just a link to your local (university) library.

Comment: @MichaelGraf Cool, and where is it referenced? Asking for a friend who doesn't find title, author, publisher or ISBN anywhere in the post.  Don't get me wrong, it's a bad post for many reasons, just without a reasonable decipherable link it's simply not a 'link only'.

Comment: @Raffzahn > the dragon book

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I bet if I kick one of my bookshelf a dozend books with dragons on the title fall out. A link is only a link when it can be followed by an average reader, not a nerd already fixiated on the topic. So again, there are many reasons to delete that post, being link only is none of them.

Comment: @Raffzahn It's [Stack Exchange jargon.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/308065)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 So answers are judged and meant only by SE-Nerd standards? Come on, I though this is supposed to be a welcoming environment? So I guess I need to repeat, there are many reasons to call this post out before settling on 'link only'

Comment: @Raffzahn To be fair, if you google "the dragon book", it's the first hit: http://letmegooglethat.com/?q=the+dragon+book&l=1

Comment: @MichaelGraf Well, I guess that's another example, that I'm not as [nerdy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXoW-TDzcFU&t=72) as other do assume ...

Comment: @Raffzahn  Your blatant hypocrisy here continues to amaze me.  You're the most unwelcoming person active on this site.

Comment: @RossRidge I do not think this is the right place to get personal. But yeah, go on :)